# Php installation tutorial gets hung up on the create database steps

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Working through the excellent [tutorial by David Powers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html), about setting up a php environment in Dreamweaver. I've hit a snag.

Down in the section "Creating a MySQL database and user account" is where I go off the rails. I create a database named 'phptest', then try to import it into my setup, and I get an error #1046.    No database selected. After investigating, I found the path that the tutorial specified for me to create the database, in htdocs/php_test/assets...did have a file named 'php_test.sql, but it was the default file that writes a databas, supplied with the tutorial.  However something WAS written to another directory,  Xampp/mysql/data.

It was a FOLDER named 'phptest', with a file in it named 'db.opt'  I can't import this folder into my project, as it will only take a database file or an archive.  So, I'm stuck and don't know what to do next...
This is on Windows 7 64 bit.  Php
I'm running the default installation of php,  as the tutorial directs. Other specs: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21  OpenSSL/1.0.0e  PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $ PHP extension: mysql   Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first switch to the `phptest` database before importing the data. To do this in phpMyAdmin, click the database in the list on the left and then select `import`.

Comment: Aha! That was it. I got it to import. I still don't understand why the step about creating a new database is this scenario.  Are the folders that are created in the mysql folder going to be used.  Is this where I'll find my database to put up on my production server?  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: MySQL is not a file-based database, you don't copy the data files, you export/import them in SQL language if you want to move them. The MySQL server handles storing the data in the files.

Comment: Another little problem.  for some reason the "start" state of the tutorial php pages are not in the package.  Ive been Trying to get the "manage_posts.php" page back to whatever state he starts in in the tutorial by cutting out chunks of php.  Still haven't got it to where it will display the 10 records without going through the security stuff.  I'd really like to go through these motions just to learn it, but I'm, once again, stuck...

Comment: Aha.  I think I got past this one!